# How to have a method call itself with parameters without a stack overflow

Tags: javascript, stack, stack-overflow, method-chaining, gsap

The following GSAP code does not work due to the function calling itself, thus looping infinitely and filling up the stack

```
var electrons = document.querySelectorAll('.electron'),
    paths = document.querySelectorAll('.path'),
    startDuration = 2;
for(var i = 0; i < electrons.length; i++) {
  var myDelay = -(i * 0.5);  
  orbit(electrons[i], paths[i], myDelay);  
}
function orbit(electron, path, delay) {
  TweenLite.to(electron, startDuration, {rotationY:'-360', ease:Linear.easeNone, 
               onComplete: orbit(electron, path, delay)}, delay);
  TweenLite.to(path, startDuration, {rotationZ:'360', ease:Linear.easeNone}, 
               delay);
}
```

**Why is the `onComplete` function being put into the stack before the animation is complete?**

If I remove the parameters from the `onComplete` orbit function call it goes into the method, but gives me an error because no parameters are given

I tried running it through a separate function, such as `function inBetween(1,2,3) { orbit(1,2,3); }` but that method didn't work (as I expected)

The reason why I need to do this is because if I put all of the electrons on the same `TweenLite` they will wait for the others to finish. Since I have negative delays this is not acceptable for me

[Here's a demo](http://codepen.io/Zeaklous/pen/sGbku) for you to play with if you'd like

Do you have any ideas on how to fix the situation?

Comment: Why use a negative delay? It would seem you should set it to 1.

Comment: @JamesBlack The negative delay is to offset the electrons so it looks less synchronized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it expect to `onComplete` be a function, try this:

```
TweenLite.to(electron, startDuration, {
        rotationY:'-360',
        ease:Linear.easeNone, 
        onComplete: function(){
            orbit(electron, path, delay);
        }
    },delay);
```

Comment: There aren't any errors, but it's not looping. Any ideas?

Comment: @ZachSaucier: put an alert before `orbit(electron, path, delay);` check if gets called.

Comment: It is indeed being called. In fact, it's repeating every two seconds. It must be a problem with my function then, I need to reset it somehow

Comment: The `onComplete` function I needed was `onComplete: function(){
      elem.restart();
    }`. Thanks for your help!